# $F$ is cumulative function, distribution of $F(X)$?

Tags: probability-theory

On wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)#Mathematical_definition

it is stated that if $X$ is a random variable where the cumulative function $F(x)=P(X\le x)$ is continuous, then $F(X)$ has a uniform distribution on [0,1]. I am wondering, is this true, and if it is, how do we prove it?

I am able to prove it in two case, on is that if $F$ is invertible. Then we have

$$P(F(X)\le z)=P(X\le F^{-1}(z))=F(F^{-1}(z))=z$$ for $z \in (0,1)$.

The second case is if $F$ is differentiable, and has a continuous distribution function $f$. Then we can calculate the characeristic function of $F(X)$ using integration by substitution and show that it is the characteristic function of a uniform distribution.

But what if we only assume that $F$ is continuous? Then we can not assume that F is one to one. And we can also not assume that it is differentiable? How is it shown then? One example of a continuous cumulative function is the Cantor function?, does the result hold then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{t: F(t) \leq z \}$ is of the form $(-\infty, s]$  for some $s$ (because of monotonicity and continuity of $F$). Hence, $P(F(X) \leq z)=P(X \leq s)=F(s)$. Since $F(s+\epsilon) >z$ for all $\epsilon >0$ we get $F(s) \geq z$. Since $F(s-\epsilon) \leq z$ for all $\epsilon >0$ we get $F(s) \leq z$ Hence, $P(F(X) \leq z)=F(s)=z$.

Comment: @user394334 I have corrected the typo.

Comment: Thanks, great answer!